# number of PCP queries

Tags: approximation-algorithms, approximation-hardness, pcp

we know from the PCP theorem that $PCP[O(log(n)),O(1)]=NP$,what if we choose specific number of queries will the theorem hold ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the best result (with regards to the number of queries) is still [Håstad's 3-query PCP](http://csce.uark.edu/~dapon/lib/Hastad.pdf). So if you choose at least 3, then it's a definite yes.

[These lecture slides](http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse533/05au/lecture16.pdf) might be a bit more useful as they cut straight to the chase.

Comment: There definitely exist 2-query PCPs. For example, Dinur's proof shows a hardness gap for 3-coloring, which corresponds to 2-query PCP with alphabet size 3.

Comment: More generically, the canonical label cover problem corresponds to a 2-query PCP with constant alphabet size. And since Max-E2-SAT is NP-hard to approximate, doesn't this imply a 2-query alphabet size 2 PCP?

Comment: @SashoNikolov: You are right that this NP-hardness implies a PCP with two queries and alphabet size 2, but this PCP will not have perfect completeness. A PCP with alphabet size 2 can not have both perfect completeness and 2 queries, since the satisfiability of 2-CNF is in P.